# How can I aggregate non consistent sub documents in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have documents similar to:

```
[
{
  group: 'x',
  key_a: 1234,
  Key_b: 3942,
  keys: { 'one': 391, 'two': 39291}
},
{
  group: 'y',
  key_a: 904,
  Key_b: 892,
  keys: { 'one': 41, 'three': 22}
}
]
```

I'd like to aggregate all the fields key_a, key b and keys together. Because keys is a map which can have any number of different fields in it, I'd like it added together maintaining the map itself as a join between each item. For example the result of the aggregation between the to documents above would have been:

```
{
  key_a: 2138,
  Key_b: 4834,
  keys: { 'one': 432, 'two':39291',  'three': 22}
}
```

is there a fast way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried? If you don't know the keys ahead of time, I'm not sure there's a way given your current structure (as Aggregation expects known field names). There might be a way if you had `keys: [ {key: 'one', value: 432} ... ]`, but even that might be quite complex and slow.

Comment: I've been doing the aggregation in Python (i.e., pulling the values and summing them up. When i get to the dict (keys) I have a function that 'adds' the two dicts together. I wanted to utilise the new aggregation framework in mongo to do the same but as you say - it requires me to know what fields are in those dicts, which I don't necessarily know.

Comment: Just a note - as it stands, aggregating in python, using the aggregation framework or using mapreduce produce results of similar performance.